# Disable Per client DNS Lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix

Is there a way to configure postfix to `disable_dns_lookups` per connecting/trusted client?

**Edit** I have an application server that I trust, which is sending me email. It sets the From, as a customer's email. However, if the customer's DNS is not working, my email server rejects the message because it can't find the IP for the email, although it was actually generated by the app server.

I simply want to turn off the DNS checks for email coming from the app server.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way. And it doesn't make sense. Why would you even want to turn that off? Spam filtering is impacted by disabling it.